# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' even when mysql.connector installed

Tags: python, anaconda, mysql-connector-python

I am having problems getting a program to import the mysql.connector
Note: Running on a Windows 10 machine.
  I have done the following

1) Installed anaconda (install properly)
   I checked that the anaconda paths are in my pathname variable
Here is the PATH var:

```
C:\Users\john.fox\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\john.fox\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\john.fox\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\john.fox\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\john.fox\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\john.fox\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python34;
```

2) Change the python version to python3.4 (was python3.6) 
   This was needed to get mysql-connector to work properly
   The Python34 path is in the pathname variable

3) Installed the mysql-connector using anaconda (installed correctly)

4) Did a "conda search mysql-connector"
   It came back with all the mysql.connectors (the one for py34_0 is present)

```
C:\Users\john.fox>conda search mysql.connector
Fetching package metadata .............
mysql-connector-python       2.0.3                    py26_0  defaults
                             2.0.3                    py27_0  defaults
                             2.0.3                    py33_0  defaults
                             2.0.3                    py34_0  defaults
                             2.0.3                    py35_0  defaults
                             2.0.4                    py27_0  defaults
                             2.0.4                    py34_0  defaults
                             2.0.4                    py35_0  defaults
                             2.0.4                    py36_0  defaults
```

5) Attempted to run a script with `import mysql.connector`
  Received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "jira_export5_Beta.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

6) Went to `Python 3.6.2` for default
7) Attempted to run again, same results.

If anyone has words of wisdom (for this problem) I would appreciate hearing them.
Thanks JWF

Comment: Hello Everyone:

Comment: It turns out that by changing the order in which the Path variable had the different items the problem cleared up. I found that putting the Ptyhon34 path in the front then closing and opening a new cmd window and then running that things worked out correctly. JWF